# How to set up partially nested resourceful routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing, nested-resources

On my Rails site, users post `Listings` of items they want to sell. Other users can browse these listings and click a link to contact the seller, which should create a `MessageThread`:

```
# MessageThread properties...
listing_id
poster_id # (listing_id's owner.. this is a shortcut for to avoid joins on the database)
sender_id
body # (text of message)
```

`MessageThreads` are never created outside the context of a `Listing`, so I nested their resourceful routes. However, they don't need the `Listing` context to be viewed/edited after they are created.. it's only necessary for the `new` and `create` actions. I set it up like this:

```
resources :message_threads, :only => [:show, :destroy]

resources :listings do
   resources :message_threads, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

I can't seem to figure out the `form_for` syntax in the `new` action view for the `MessageThreadsController`... I do `form_for @message_thread` but that isn't working. Is this the right way to set this object up? Should I avoid using resourceful routes, or maybe pass the listing ID as a parameter in the URL, instead of nesting the routes? Or always reference the message_thread underneath a listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
form_for @message_thread, :url => listing_message_threads_path(@listing)
```

You can always run this in the command line

```
rake routes | grep message_thread
```

The new link would be

```
new_listing_message_threads_path(@listing)
```